# what is the difference between assigning one object to another object and returning object and assigning it to another object in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

so if we create two object

```
var dog = {
var name:"dog",
    makeSound: function(){
    alert("wow");
    }

}


var cate = {
var name:"cate",
    makeSound: function(){
    alert("meow");
    }

}

cate = dog;
```

now both `cate` and `dog` point to same object.

and if we do it like this

```
cate = object.create(dog);
```

what is the difference between the two is `cate` and `dog` point to same object now?

Answer (score 0):

**object.create**

> Creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties.

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Not with the same **values**!

While `cate = dog;` just tells `cate` to point to the same reference as `dog`.